# PushApps API - Devices and DeviceIds parameters

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging, pushapps

Using PushApps Remote Server API , What is the difference between “Devices” and “DeviceIds” parameters in CreateNotification method and can I use them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Devices** you specify a push token and a device type.
In **DeviceIds** you just specify the Id received from PushApps SDK.
You can use both of them together, duplicate devices within the same request will be ignored.
By the way, if you use one of this parameters you cannot use **Platforms** parameter.

Let me know if it answers your question.